# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactInternals.ReactCurrentOwner')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I was writing an app and everything was OK till I had to install and use react-native-router-flux.
Seems like something's wrong with it's version but I can't find it.
This is the error I get (from the line that I import react-native-router-flux):

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactInternals.ReactCurrentOwner')
```

I've searched for it but none of the suggestions worked!
Appreciate it if someone can help me.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Manager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.43.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-static-container": "^1.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

P.S: when I try to update my react-native-router-flux, I get this error from npm:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

Comment: try with react version `react@16.0.0-alpha.12` - `npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.12 --save`

Comment: @AravindS Surprisingly it worked!!! thanks

Comment: Happy to know.i will add it as an answer, accept it so that it will helpful for others who look for similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.12 --save` or `yarn add react@16.0.0-alpha.12`. Track the github issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13874)